# Is it possible to achieve string localization inside of a statically linked lib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsbundle, mobiledevice.framework

I am working on building an SDK which will be built out as a statically linked library that third party applications can then drop in to their applications. Inside of this SDK, I was looking to be able to perform some "localization." Basically, I would like for the code in my SDK to be able to access some ".string" files to perform some string lookup and language translation capabilities. Then I could propagate these strings outward to implementing App layers through my exposed API's. Is this even possible? I thought it was but now that I have actually been trying, I am seriously having doubts.

Comment: FYI, if you're really targeting iOS, iOS apps don't support third-party frameworks and only support statically linked libraries.

Comment: From Apple's documentation: "You may create your own frameworks for OS X, but third-party frameworks are not allowed on iOS." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Framework.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make specific API to make the localized strings to be fed into the static library. One way for achieving it is by defining a predefined key value pair for all your library strings and ask end user to provide a localized files if a new language needs to be supported.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on this? I am a bit confused by your answer.. I am new to iOS programming so please do not get upset just really looking for some help, been trying to solve this all day.

Comment: The static library is also copied to your application bundle. You can feed string to static library in the same way as you localize other strings. If you are ok to expose the localization keys, then ask the end user to add the localization file when using the library.

Comment: I do not want any end user to be supplying string files, I want the localized.string files to be in house. Just wondering how my code inside my statically linked lib can then access these "in-house" resources..

Comment: You can have different resource files for different languages and load the file based on the language. Embedded the resource file in your library.